# Mapbox Geocoding and Markers

Tags: javascript, geocoding, mapbox, markers

I recently added Mapbox's Geocoder Control and it works wonderfully. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I could have a marker appear at the location of the address that was searched for? Below is the code I'm currently using for the control.

.addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
    position: 'topright',
    keepOpen: false,
    autocomplete: false
}))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonatas' answer works great. If you're using the goecode autocomplete, use the 'select' event instead of the 'found' event.  Here is how I place a marker for the geocoded result:

```
    var geocoderControl = L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {keepOpen: false, autocomplete: true});
    geocoderControl.addTo(map);


    geocoderControl.on('select', function(object){
       var coord = object.feature.geometry.coordinates;
       L.marker([coord[1], coord[0]]).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `found` [event for this in mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geolocation/). Not tested, but something like this should work:

```
// add the control and keep a reference to it
var geocoderControl = L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', { position: 'topright', keepOpen: false, autocomplete: false });
geocoderControl.addTo(map);

// listen for the found event and add a marker
geocoderControl.on('found', function(res) {
    var feature = res.results.features[0];
    L.marker(feature.geometry.coordinates).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as it follows:

```
var geocoder_control = L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
    keepOpen: false
});
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').addControl(geocoder_control);


geocoder_control.on('select', function(object){
    var coord = object.feature.geometry.coordinates;

    L.mapbox.featureLayer({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: coord
        },
        properties: {
            title: 'Peregrine Espresso',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-color': '#BE9A6B',
            'marker-symbol': 'cafe'
        }
    }).addTo(map);

});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/joOXJ6?p=preview)