# Mapbox GL JS Geocoder marker

Tags: javascript, geocoding, mapbox, markers, mapbox-gl-js

I'm still a js noob.

I am currently developing a map using the Mapbox GL JS API with their geocoding plugin, however, I'm am not seeing any examples of adding a marker after the return.

I did find a previous thread ([Mapbox Geocoding and Markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148985/mapbox-geocoding-and-markers/158767#158767)) with the same question, however, this is referring to the js api and appears to be using a different syntax.

Here is my code thus far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title></title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.2/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.2/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v0.0.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v0.0.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = <token>;
if (!mapboxgl.supported()) {
alert('Your browser does not support Mapbox GL');
} else {
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/<user.id>/<style.id>',
    center: [-122.654422, 45.5434085],
    zoom: 11
});
}
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Geocoder('top-left'));
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation({position: 'top-right'}));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to the API: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to listen for the *geocoder.input* and to create a point based on the result.

```
geocoder.on('geocoder.input', function(ev) {
  map.getSource('single-point').setData(ev.result.geometry);
});
```

Here's an example demonstrating it: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/point-from-geocoder-result/